# Why doesnt my SQL Update query with increment/decrement execute from Pentaho on Derby?

Tags: java, sql, derby, pentaho, kettle

I'm trying to execute `SQL` query using `Pentaho` on `Derby` database? 
The query is very simple. It's to update the value of column to increase/decrease 1 on it.

[image]

When I modified the query to this :
`UPDATE APP.PROCLOGS SET FAIL = 22 WHERE ID = ${pid}`,
it works normal.

So why am I unable to execute this query to increase/decrease the value of the column?

Regards,

Comment: what says the error log output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **question mark** to use the fields name as an argument:

```
UPDATE APP.PROCLOGS SET FAIL = ? WHERE ID = ${pid}
```

if you need to increment the FAIL value +1 do it in previous step. the ? placeholder can not handle this operation.

Answer (score 3):

Check the data type of `FAIL`. If it's a numerical type such as `INT`, it should work if you set `FAIL = FAIL + 1`.

If it's not a numerical type, for example if it's a character string type such as `VARCHAR` it will fail.

```
MY_STRING = MY_STRING + 1  ---doesn't make sense
```

However, if you set `FAIL = 22` (assuming `FAIL` is a `VARCHAR` type), this will work because `22` will be automatically converted (cast)  to a `VARCHAR` representation